# Heterogeneous vs Homogeneous

Tags: data-structures, types

I'm little bit confused about heterogeneous and homogeneous list and array. In OOP context, if I define base class and it's derived class, why is array of base class homogeneous, if I can store derived classes as well? It's same principle, as void pointer in C (i.e. https://gist.github.com/rawcoder/9720851 ). Every literature says, that homogeneous structure is of same type (semantically), so can you please explain this to me little bit more further?

Comment: Derived class instances are still is-a parent class instance. In that sense it's homogenous-plus the list itself is declared as a parent-class list, so when you access list members, you're working with the parent class definition, e.g., you can't call a method on a member defined only in the child class without casting.

Comment: Look at this post and comments - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943915/collections-of-different-types-inherited-from-a-single-object-vs-a-single-collec , where is difference?

Comment: Difference between what and what?

Comment: Difference in his logic and mine. He says, that `List<Shape>` is heterogeneous, but `List<Circle>` is homogeneous. Is the distinguish in the manipulation?

If he did not use `If (shape instance of XY) {....}`, but used polymorphism instead, would be the `List<Shape>` still heterogeneous?

Comment: A `List<Shape>` is a list of `Shape`. What you do with the contents of that list is irrelevant; using `instanceof` doesn't change list contents. It allows you to manipulate list members based on what they *really* are, which might be necessary if your class design is awful, or your requirements change. Not sure why you're focusing on someone's usage of the two words.

Comment: Personally as a kind of low-level C coder I tend to refer to collections of polymorphic base pointers as "non-homogeneous", as it is non-homogeneous in all the respects that kind of matter in my context. The data is not necessarily of a uniform size and it cannot be represented contiguously in a very practical way, and calling functions into these shapes does not necessarily cause uniform side effects with the dynamic dispatch. For all the lower-level bits and bytes details that matter to me, it's not homogeneous data.

Comment: Besides, if `List<Shape>` counts as homogeneous, then what doesn't count as homogeneous? Most languages do not allow disparate data types to be stored in a container without at least one level of indirection, since the size of each data type may not match and that would be extremely awkward to code a general container against. Maybe some kind of variant type with code looping through it and manually checking its type might count as a violation of homogeneity, but personally I think it's more useful to think of lists of polymorphic base pointers as also non-homogeneous. Maybe I'm too low-level.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of putting it is that instances of a derived type *are* instances of a base type, so can be stored in a collection of the base type.

It has more to do with the *type* of the *collection* than what's stored in it. If a collection has type `array[B]`, and `D < B` (type D derives from B), then storing a `D` in an `array[B]` doesn't violate the type of the array or operations on the array/elements of the array. However, if the array were defined to hold only descendants of `B` but not `B` itself (e.g. `array[ D < B ]`; `array<D extends B>` in Java-speak), then it would be heterogenous, because it's declared to hold multiple types, rather than a single type. Note that in some programming languages, "heterogeneous" means holds *any* type (e.g. `array[Any?]`, `array<*>`), not just multiple different types.

Outside of such languages, [union types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type) muddy the waters, because they allow disparate types to be treated as one. `array[A | B | C]` could be viewed as heterogeneous, or as the homogeneous `array[U]`, where `U = A | B | C`.

The point of a type system in programming is to ensure a certain level of correctness by restricting what is allowed, based on type. Homogeneity strengthens the typing system, while unions weaken typing, as they:

- can allow an instance of one type to be treated as another, causing a run-time type violation, and
- allow for some types to not be handled, which is potentially another error.

Some type systems avoid these by using the more restricted [sum type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_type) (aka "variant type"), which includes type information along with instances, instead of using union types. This prevents both the above issues with union types, restoring homogeneity. However, type systems that have sum types are usually so strong that the concepts of homogeneity and heretogeneity aren't as useful (basically, every collection is homogeneous, even the heterogeneous ones, which are collections of the maximal type from which all other types descend; consider the `array[Any?]` example above).

Storing subtypes in a homogeneous collection is a consequence of the [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which states that a property of a type should be true of a subtype (i.e. subtypes should be substitutable in contexts in place of a supertype). If the method (e.g. `operator[]`, `add`) that adds an element to an array takes type `B`, it should also take subtypes. If code operates on elements of a collection expecting they're of type `B`, it should operate just as correctly on subtypes.

Note this is distinct from the matter of subtype relationships between collection types (e.g. if `D < B`, is `array[D] < array[B]`?), which is a matter of [(type) variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)).